# Need some Kmean on Hadoop Mapreduce Examples

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, k-means

I need some example of Kmean on MapReduce process clustering on multiple file contain text name. After that a use a search program to search text on clusters output. I'm newbie with this. I want to learn and use Kmean on Mapreduce. I hope i will receive help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Mahout, which includes [k-means implementation for Hadoop](https://mahout.apache.org/users/clustering/k-means-clustering.html).